# Adding Text to A Shell Script for Simple Program

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to create a really simple shell program, and I am having some difficulty trying to get it to work. I feel like my program matches the syntax that I see out on the internet, but my program just does not work.

The basic thing I need my program to do is to display the time, date, who is logged in, and the listing of the user's home directory. It also needs to take in a file name as a parameter.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=1
echo -n 'The time is: ' >> $filename
date +"%H:%M" >> $filename
echo -n 'The date is: ' >> $filename
date +'%d/%m/%Y' >> $filename
echo -n 'Who is currently logged in: ' >> $filename
who >> $filename
echo 'What is in their home directory: ' >> $filename
ls $HOME >> $filename
```

The time, date, who's logged in, and the listing all output correctly to my output file.

The issue that I am having is my echo text does not seem to be going to my file, and I am clueless as to why since it matches pretty much exactly to what I have seen online and in my textbook.

Can someone let me know where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: The output is logged to file `1`, for the first parameter it should be `$1`.

Comment: @Freddy Thanks! That's what did it! Can you answer the question for me so I can give you credit?